# Printing the current date/time with sub-second precision

Tags: command-line

GNU `date(1)` understands the `%N` format spec, which outputs nanoseconds, so:

```
$ date +%H:%m:%S.%N
```

outputs 19:10:03.725196000

BSD date doesn't understand %N. How can I print the current time with sub-second precision on OS X?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, BSD `date` doesn't support `%N`. So the straightforward solution is to download GNU's `date` and install it to either `~/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` and call that when you need to use `%N`.

However, I would not advise replacing the version that ships with your Mac with the new one. Most of these coreutil programs are written such that their output can be understood by *other programs*, not necessarily humans, so reliability in output is a necessity. There might be several scripts in your mac that parse the output of *BSD's* `date` and any possible changes introduced by replacing with GNU's might or might not break things.

---

The simplest way to do this safely on a Mac is to use `homebrew` and install coreutils.

```
brew info coreutils
coreutils 8.16
http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils
...   
==> Caveats
All commands have been installed with the prefix 'g'.
```

The GNU equivalent will be named `gdate` and is located in `/usr/local/Cellar/coreutils/8.16/bin/`. You can also set an alias in your `.bashrc` or its equivalent as

```
alias date='gdate'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use python. It's built into macOS, so you don't need to install additional software!

```
python -c 'import datetime; print datetime.datetime.now()'
```

If you want the output to be formatted differently, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/18944849/6358721

Comment: even if it might be slightly overkill, if you need precision and compatibility, it's a good choice.

Comment: @Ajax One thing to be careful of—at the time this answer was written, `python` shipped with macOS. This is no longer the case as of this writing in 2023.

Comment: thanks for the heads up! sounds like I need to do `py_exec=python3 ; command -v python3 &>/dev/null || py_exec=python ; $py_exc -c '...'`  ....yuck :-/

Comment: @Ajax Note that even python3 does not ship with macOS, it comes with the developer tools.

Comment: Ah, thanks for letting me know.  Since everyone at my company has developer tools installed, I feel safe using this as my "timestamps for bash": `python3 -c "from datetime import datetime; print(datetime.now().strftime('%y-%m-%d.%H-%M-%S.%f'))"`

Comment: Were I writing a generic utility for public consumption, I'd obviously not make any assumptions, but for my use cases, python3 works.