# Renaming All Files in a Folder with Date and Timestamp, Adding Counter if Duplicate

Tags: terminal, command-line, bash

After taking a look at [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360917/rename-file-names-in-directory-to-creation-timestamp-with-second-precision) and adapting to my needs, I am stuck when there are files with identical timestamps.

I need to rename all files in a folder, including the date and timestamp at end. However, if any two files share the same date and timestamp, then my shell script doesn't work property.  In that case, I thought the best solution would be to add a number, incrementing by one, each time there is a file with an identical timestamp.

The files should look like this:

```
photo_2019_12_23_22_20_35_001.jpg
photo_2019_12_23_22_20_35_002.jpg
photo_2019_12_23_22_20_35_003.jpg
photo_2019_12_23_22_20_36_001.jpg
```

Here is the code as I have it now:

```
for f in *.*; do 
    mv -n "$f" "photo-$(stat -f'%SB' -t "%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M_%S" "$f").${f##*.}"
done
```

Comment: You could apply one of the answers from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29320/printing-the-current-date-time-with-sub-second-precision to get more precision.

Comment: Instead of a sequential number, you could append a checksum, such as output by `sum`. Or the first few characters of `md5`.